# Can't get a Chocolatey package approved (issues with URLs)

Tags: chocolatey, nuspec

I'm struggling to get my *Chocolatey* package accepted. Mostly, it says something like *LicenseUrl* is invalid, When I resubmit with no change (that URL is valid and accessible), it says the same about *DocsUrl* but again, it is valid and accessible.

So I'm fighting endlessly and just making circles. Could anyone please spot the issue? Could it be like every URL must be unique (though that amount of URLs is excessive for a small command-line utility)? Please don't worry about the case of the tag names: the error messages have them in *TitleCase*, but in the .nuspec files they are specified in *camelCase*. Also I don't think that the absense of the *requireLicenseAcceptance* causes the issue, especially, when it is not related to *licenseUrl*.

Here is the .nuspec file. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>xnx</id>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
    <authors>Alexander Iurovetski</authors>
    <owners>Alexander Iurovetski</owners>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2023 Alexander Iurovetski</copyright>
    <packageSourceUrl>https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/xnx/0.2.0</packageSourceUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://aiurovet.com/applications/xnx.html</projectUrl>
    <docsUrl>https://aiurovet.com/applications/xnx.html</docsUrl>
    <wikiUrl>https://aiurovet.com/applications/xnx.html</wikiUrl>
    <projectSourceUrl>https://github.com/aiurovet/xnx/tree/0.2.0</projectSourceUrl>
    <bugTrackerUrl>https://github.com/aiurovet/xnx/issues</bugTrackerUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aiurovet/xnx/0.2.0/scripts/mkicons/xnx_192x192.svg</iconUrl>
    <licenseUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aiurovet/xnx/0.2.0/LICENSE.txt</licenseUrl>
    <mailingListUrl>mailto:xxx@gmail.com</mailingListUrl>
    <releaseNotes>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aiurovet/xnx/0.2.0/CHANGELOG.md</releaseNotes>
    <tags>utility cli</tags>
    <title>xnx</title>
    <summary>
      Smart search and replace followed by calling external executables.
    </summary>
    <description>
      Command-line utility for Linux, macOS and Windows performing sophisticated
      search and replace followed by calling external executables. It can be
      considered a kind of JSON shell.
    </description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="*.ico" target="tools" />
    <file src="..\..\..\*.md" target="" />
    <file src="..\..\..\*.txt" target="" />
    <file src="..\..\..\*.xnxconfig" target="tools" />
    <file src="tools\**" target="tools" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: There are sometimes known issues with URL validation, as noted here https://github.com/chocolatey/home/issues/144 I would suggest that you respond via the Package Moderation page, and ask for a moderator to take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Gary Ewan Park. Could you please give me a link to the Package Moderation page? I struggled to find that by myself. If it is package-specific, then possibly, just the URL format?

Comment: It will be the same panel notifying you of the URL failures, e.g. on `https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/{PackageID}` when you are logged in to the package maintainer account - in this case, it looks like it is https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/xnx.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JamesRuskin. So all I need is just to add the comment at the bottom, right?

Comment: Yep! Just respond to the latest validation report with a "hey, these URLs seem valid to me" (or similar) and linking to the issue Gary provided above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JamesRuskin and Gary Ewan Park. I'm communicating with the support engineers already.